# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \arctan(n^2)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know I can't prove this one with Leibniz, because $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \arctan(n^2) = \frac \pi 2 \ne 0 $.
With which kind of test should I prove it?

EDIT: Okay thanks, Maple calculated and gave the result of -.1729004752 but I guess that's not right then?

Comment: A necessary condition for the convergence of a series is that the terms converge to $0$.

Comment: Okay thanks, Maple calculated and gave the result of -.1729004752 but I guess that's not right then?

Comment: Maple must be high.  Don't trust it blindly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(n^2)=\frac\pi2$$
then the general term of the series doesn't tend to $0$ so the series is divergent.

Comment: Okay thanks, Maple calculated and gave the result of -.1729004752 but I guess that's not right then?

Comment: This series isn't convergent and notice that for $n$ sufficiently large the partial sum $S_n$ verify:
$$S_{n+1}-S_n\approx \pm\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 5):

By writing the LHS as the argument of an infinite product, then using the Weierstrass product for the sine and cosine function, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \arctan\frac{1}{n^2}=-\arctan\left(\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}-\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sinh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}+\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)=-0.6124976882\ldots\tag{1}$$
hence the value returned by Maple is just the Césaro sum of the series, namely:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}}^*(-1)^n \arctan n^2&=&\arctan\left(\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}-\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sinh\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}+\sin\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\\&=&-\arctan\frac{\sin(\pi/\sqrt{2})}{\sinh(\pi/\sqrt{2})}\\&=&-0.17290047519068984988\ldots.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
It is a common issue of many Computer Algebra Systems to incorrectly deal with non-converging series, returning the Césaro sum instead of a warning. I remember old versions of Mathematica giving
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\cos(\pi n) = \frac{1}{2},$$
for instance, so I am not surprised of this strange behaviour.

Comment: Maple has documented [this behavior](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalf%2FSum). When you pass an infinite sum to an `evalf(sum())` construct, Maple will use something called Levin's u-transform to evaluate the sum. It has a side effect that **sums that formally diverge may return a result that can be interpreted as evaluation of the analytic extension of the series for the sum**.

Answer (score 1):

You've just demonstrated that it doesn't converge, because it fails the limit test.

Comment: That's weird, my Calculus program (Maple) can calculate it so I thought it converged?

Comment: @ArnePeeters: have a look at my answer for an explanation :)